# CSS media queries ignores order of preference

Tags: css, media-queries

It's simple, I have a CSS that should apply to `<body>`, but doesn't apply.

```
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 600px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait){
    body{
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

Is in the order that I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is actually getting applied correctly.

In CSS, if two rules have the same origin, weight and specificity, then the one declared last overrides the previous one. So in your case, `margin-left: 5px;` and `margin-right: 5px;` are getting applied but they are immediately getting overridden by `margin: 0 0 0 0;`.

So all you have to do is change the order. Like this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #212121;
}
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 600px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait){
    body{
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't a rule apply to all the rules below it?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code, its just your ordering. In a responsive web design, you should use `"mobile-first"` CSS. this means that your media queries should be AFTER your default css:

```
body {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
background-color: #212121;
}

  @media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 600px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait){
    body{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;

    }
}
```